# SharePoint 2013 user reports

Tags: search, site, user, access

In a previous version of SharePoint, I was able to export a list of most frequent site visitors (their name actually displayed) but when I export the usage report in SharePoint 2013, it only provides a date and number of unique site visitors.  Has the actual population of site visitor names been deactivated?  Thanks!

Comment: Is my answer helps you?

Answer (score 0):

According to IFABC Global Web Standards, a unique visitor is an IP address plus a further identifier (such as user name, user agent, or a cookie). If you want to know how many daily unique visitors there are, you should go to the Site Collection Web Analytics Reports – Number of Daily Unique Visitors page. The Summary page is nothing more than a summation of all days and all unique visitors.

Is this a bad thing? We feel it is at least a little (okay, more than just a little). It makes sense to provide overviews of the number of unique visitors per day, week, month, year or whatever. By simply summarizing all unique visitors, soon the number of unique visitors on the Summary page goes sky high. It leads to a situation where web analytic reports show that there are 1000 unique visitors, whereas in reality there are only 100. We know it’s a summary page, but we also feel this is a situation where simple math doesn’t apply to this data and leads to confusing results.

Please check below link for further details.

[Web analytics unique visitors go sky high](https://sharepointdragons.com/2012/01/12/web-analytics-unique-visitors-go-sky-high/)

> Number of Daily Unique Visitors: Total number of unique visitors each
>   day. SharePoint authenticated users and anonymous users (using IP
>   address) are counted as visitors.

[Web Analytics in SharePoint 2010: Insights into Reports and Metrics](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ecm/2010/05/03/web-analytics-in-sharepoint-2010-insights-into-reports-and-metrics/)

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks Hardik.  One question though - in SharePoint 2013, if I click on site settings, the only link I can find is "Popularity Trends".  When I click on that, it brings me to the one canned report but no detail regarding visitor names.  Any thoughts?

Comment: I think you need full permission on the site to generate the report.

Comment: Did you get it working for you?